# jquery Switch Case

Tags: php, jquery

Here you can find my jQuery-code :

```
function ledgerSave(){
            var option = $('#ledgerType').val();
            var ledger = $('#ledgerName').val();

            switch( option ) {
                case ( option == 0 ) :
                    alert( 'Select Your Ledger Type' );
                    break;

                case ( option == 1 ) :
                    /* some code */
                break;

                case ( option == 2 ) :
                    /* some code */
                break;

                case ( option == 3 ) :
                    /* some code */
                break;
            }
        }
```

In the variable "option" I'm getting the select values as 0,1,2 and 3.
so I do the alert when the variable option has a value 0 in it, but it shows no alert. I don't understand where the actual problem is. need help !

I also tried this :

```
function ledgerSave(){
            var option = $('#ledgerType').val();
            var ledger = $('#ledgerName').val();

            switch( option ) {
                case 0:
                    alert( 'Select Your Ledger Type' );
                    break;

                case 1:
                    /* some code */
                break;

                case 2:
                    /* some code */
                break;

                case 3:
                    /* some code */
                break;
            }
        }
```

but no good.

Comment: convert it in int using parseInt(#ledgerType).val()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is option is a string where as in [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) you have number. So you should convert the option to a number, you can use a unary operator or use parseInt().

> The program first looks for a case clause whose expression evaluates
>   to the same value as the input expression (using [strict comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators),
>   ===) and then transfers control to that clause, executing the associated statements.

```
var option = +$('#ledgerType').val();//or parseInt($('#ledgerType').val(), 10)
```

Note: You still have to use the second version of switch...case

```
function ledgerSave() {
    var option = +$('#ledgerType').val();
    var ledger = $('#ledgerName').val();

    switch (option) {
        case 0:
            alert('Select Your Ledger Type');
            break;

        case 1:
            /* some code */
            break;

        case 2:
            /* some code */
            break;

        case 3:
            /* some code */
            break;
    }
}
```

---

As noted below another option is use do a string comparison

```
function ledgerSave() {
    var option = $('#ledgerType').val();
    var ledger = $('#ledgerName').val();

    switch (option) {
        case '0':
            alert('Select Your Ledger Type');
            break;

        case '1':
            /* some code */
            break;

        case '2':
            /* some code */
            break;

        case '3':
            /* some code */
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks bro. but i also another solution like: case '1' : /* do some */ break; and it works. but i will go with yours. thanks.

Comment: @vitally yes... as the documentation says a strict comparison is done... so either convert the option to number or change the cases to string type